# Serialize Object Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to serialize an object to Azure Mobile Services.

The object contains an array of a second object which should also be serialized.

```
[DataContract()]
class ObjectA
{
    [DataMember(Name= "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "info")]
    public string info{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "collectionOfB")]
    public ObjectB[] myArrayOfB{ get; set; }
}

[DataContract()]
class ObjectB
{
    [DataMember(Name= "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "info")]
    public string info{ get; set; }
}
```

I have loaded both table's properly and can insert an individual item into each of the tables.

However when I call the InsertAsync method on the table for objectA I receive an error

```
Cannot serialize member 'myArrayOfB' of type 'namespace.ObjectB[]' declared on type 'ObjectA'
```

Any idea's on what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mobile Services doesn't support serialization of arrays. There are two good posts here that show how you might support this:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/08/30/supporting-arbitrary-types-in-azure-mobile-services-managed-client-simple-types.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/09/11/supporting-complex-types-in-azure-mobile-services-clients-implementing-1-n-table-relationships.aspx

Comment: Thanks I found the second post and am working on the implementation now.